# How to filter SQL query based on value in another table

Tags: mysql

I'm new to SQL queries and are trying to figure out how to filter my output somehow.

The function I want to achieve is that multiple users can be listed as authors on a single entry, AND, also the possibility to filter the search result by using a drop-down menu or something like that to see which entries an author is listed too.

I currently have two tables in my database, one is called ENTRIES and the other is AUTHORS

Each of the tables looks like this:

```
+-------------------------------+       +---------------------------------+
DB: ENTRIES // To keep all entries.     DB: AUTHORS // To keep track of which authors that are listed to each entry.
+-------------------------------+       +---------------------------------+
ID   TITLE    DATE                      ID   AUTHOR1    AUTHOR2    AUTHOR3
1    NAME     2018-03-19                1    TRUE       FALSE      TRUE
2    NAME     2018-03-20                2    FALSE      TRUE       FALSE
3    NAME     2018-03-21                3    TRUE       FALSE      FALSE
+-------------------------------+       +---------------------------------+
```

My SQL query looks like this right now:

```
$query = "
 SELECT * FROM ENTRIES INNER JOIN AUTHORS ON ENTRIES.ID=AUTHORS.ID;
 ";
}
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
```

I get it to list all the results but I don't know how to filter the results based on the value in the AUTHORS table? And are INNER JOIN the right way to go?

The result should be something like:

```
FILTER ON: ALL / NAME / NAME / NAME

#####################################################
# 1  TITLE     AUTHOR 1 AUTHOR 3         DATE       #
#####################################################

#####################################################
# 2  TITLE     AUTHOR 2                  DATE       #
#####################################################

#####################################################
# 3  TITLE     AUTHOR 1                  DATE       #
#####################################################
```

Comment: You want to use where condition in AUTHORS table?

Comment: I am not clear what you are asking for - are you asking for all authors for a specified entry (ie all trues) , or all entries for a specified author?

Comment: If you add an example of what you expect the result to look like someone will definitely be able to help you.

Comment: @Pragya $P.Salmon I want to list all ENTRIES, with the AUTHORS that are true also listed in the same entry, then I want to be able to filter the ENTRIES on the AUTHORS that are listed in each entry.

Comment: @NicklasOlofsson Can you please add the result? In above tables what should be the exact result?

Comment: @Pragya Updated the entry with the look I want of the result, please check it out. Thanks!

Comment: You want the fields name of the table? right?

Answer (score -2):

You have to use subqueries.

```
SELECT * FROM entries e
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT id FROM authors a WHERE e.id = a.id)
```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/subqueries.html